# Elasticsearch Nested Match Last Value

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nested

We have article & edited authors as array. Need to check How many article last edited by particular author.

***Data:***

```
{
    "Article" : [
      {
        "id" : 12
        "title" : "An article title",
        "categories" : [1,3,5,7],
        "tag" : ["elasticsearch", "symfony",'Obtao'],
        "author" : [
            {
                "firstname" : "Francois",
                "surname": "francoisg",
                "id" : 18
            },
            {
                "firstname" : "Gregory",
                "surname" : "gregquat"
                "id" : "2"
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
        "id" : 13
        "title" : "A second article title",
        "categories" : [1,7],
        "tag" : ["elasticsearch", "symfony",'Obtao'],
        "author" : [
            {
                "firstname" : "Gregory",
                "surname" : "gregquat",
                "id" : "2"
            },
            {
                "firstname" : "Francois",
                "surname": "francoisg",
                "id" : 18
            }
        ]
      }
}
```

***Request Data:***
    URL: http://localhost:9200/book/articles/_count/

```
For example `Gregory` & `Francois` should get one article as count.
```

Please let me know how to compare first object only & get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't filter directly, But can able to solve this issue, by adding the extra property in last edited author.

```
{
    "Article" : [
      {
        "id" : 12
        "title" : "An article title",
        "categories" : [1,3,5,7],
        "tag" : ["elasticsearch", "symfony",'Obtao'],
        "author" : [
            {
                "firstname" : "Francois",
                "surname": "francoisg",
                "id" : 18,
                "is_last_edited_staff": true
            },
            {
                "firstname" : "Gregory",
                "surname" : "gregquat"
                "id" : "2",
                "is_last_edited_staff": false
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
        "id" : 13
        "title" : "A second article title",
        "categories" : [1,7],
        "tag" : ["elasticsearch", "symfony",'Obtao'],
        "author" : [
            {
                "firstname" : "Gregory",
                "surname" : "gregquat",
                "id" : "2",
                "is_last_edited_staff": true
            },
            {
                "firstname" : "Francois",
                "surname": "francoisg",
                "id" : 18,
                "is_last_edited_staff": false
            }
        ]
      }
}
```